# Subqueries with Define

Tags: sql, oracle, query-optimization, database-performance, sqlperformance

Subqueries with define

I have a question, about using DEFINE in real word.

I've just modified the code from the lecture a little bit by defining the employee we are working with at the beginning and then using that defined variable in code like this:

```
DEFINE employee = "(select * from employees where employee_id = 145)";
 
-- all employees that work in the same department as 'defined employee'
SELECT *
FROM   employees
WHERE  department_id = (SELECT department_id 
                        FROM   &employee        -- here using that variable
                       );
```

Is this solution smart? And is this something you would do in real word?

I mean if we will have a lot of queries with the same person then later instead of changing each query cause we will have to change the employee_id , we could just change the id in the define variable and everything will still be working.

Or should I even define more variables like:

```
define salary = ...
define department = ...
```

For memory optimization, so we do not return all the employees' information but only the ones we really need?

Comment: How are you going to use the script? e.g. is this part of a batch job?

Comment: "is this something you would do in real word?" No, this is not something that I would do. If you want to store variables to re-use between queries then use PL/SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Good idea, but not the best way to implement. Google for "SQL injection" to see one reason.

Better: use views for the `select` statement you "defined", and reference the view whenever needed. And use **bind variables** (Google to find links that teach you how to use bind variables) for things like the employee id, or the department, etc. This will protect from SQL injection, and is much more efficient because the queries will not need to be recompiled each time the inputs change (which will happen with your approach).

Comment: I see someone downvoted my answer. An explanation of what they found wrong with it would help. Without it, it looks more like vandalism.

Answer (score 1):

[`DEFINE`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqpug/DEFINE.html#GUID-72D4998C-EC2C-4FA6-9F7F-A305C407D666) is a SQL*Plus command that is simple substitution. It has nothing about SQL language. It cannot be used in queries via, for example, ODBC or JDBC, so its practical usage is limited by automation of your own work, when you may have bunch of your favourite prepared scripts and want so parameterize them for flexibility.

If you connect via SQL*Plus, then you already have database credentials and already can do much inside the database, so this is not for end user.

Here's the nice article on this topic: [SQL*Plus Substitution Variables - DEFINE variables and parameters in SQL Queries](https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/sqlplus-101-substitution-variables).

To use user input you need bind variables: they accept the data, not some peace of text and never mixed with SQL tokens like keywords, identifiers, functions etc.

So the conclusion: if you feel good having this for your own routine tasks, it may be ok. But not for release to users.